# Contract.methods.myFunc().send() not executed

Tags: javascript, solidity

The function is called:

```
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(CONTRACT.abi, contractAddress);

await contract.methods.sendToOwner().send({ from: currentAccount.address })
    .then(receipt => {
        console.log(receipt);
    });
```

Receipt returned successfully, but the function `sendToOwner()` is not executed
this is solidity test code:

```
contract UserAcc {
    address owner;
    bool isGetEther;
    bool isSendToOwner;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(
            msg.sender == owner,
            "Only the contract administrator can call this function!"
        );
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyOneTranOrOnlyOwner() {
        require(!isGetEther || msg.sender == owner, 
        "Only the one transaction can be by other users!");
        _;
    }

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    receive() external payable onlyOneTranOrOnlyOwner {
        if (msg.value != 0 && !isGetEther) {
            isGetEther = true;
        }
    }

    fallback() external payable onlyOneTranOrOnlyOwner {
        if (msg.value != 0 && !isGetEther) {
            isGetEther = true;
        }
    }

    function getBalance() public view onlyOwner returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function getOwner() public view onlyOwner returns(address) {
        return owner;
    }

    function getIsSendToOwner() public view onlyOwner returns(bool) {
        return isSendToOwner;
    }

    function sendToOwner() public onlyOwner {
        (bool success, ) = owner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(success, "Transaction failed!");
        isSendToOwner = true;
    }

}
```

If the function were executed, then `getIsSendToOwner() return true`, but since it is not executed, it `return false`.

Upd:
I was able to solve this problem by changing the code:

```
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(CONTRACT.abi, contractAddress);

const transactionParameters = {
    to: contractAddress,
    from: currentAccount.address,
    data: contract.methods.sendToOwner().encodeABI()
};

await window.ethereum.request({
    method: "eth_sendTransaction",
    params: [transactionParameters],
})
    .then(receipt => {
        console.log(receipt);
    });
```

Comment: Cannot fully reproduce your issue - so here's at least a generic hint: Your `sendToOwner()` function uses a custom `onlyOwner` modifier. This modifier in your code implements a validation that the function can be only executed by a specific `owner` address - otherwise the execution fails. It's possible that your `currentAccount.address` is not the authorized `owner` address.

Comment: @PetrHejda, ```currentAccount.address```this is the address of the person who deployed the smart contract, the rest of the functions with the ```onlyOwner``` modifier perform well and send a correct response (```getBalance()```, ```getIsSendToOwner()```). So I cant image what the problem might be, maybe I'm calling the client-side method incorrectly